# Can't disable suggestions in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying to disable suggestions in VSC by changing the following in settings.json, but it hasnt works for me. What am I doing wrong?

````
    // OPTIONAL WORD WRAPPING
    // Controls if lines should wrap. The lines will wrap at min(editor.wrappingColumn, viewportWidthInColumns).
    "editor.wordWrap": "off",

    // Controls the indentation of wrapped lines. Can be one of 'none', 'same' or 'indent'.
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "none",

    // TURN OFF AUTOCOMPLETION
    // Controls if quick suggestions should show up or not while typing
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false,

    // Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 90,

    // Enables parameter hints
    "editor.parameterHints": false,

    // Controls if the editor should automatically close brackets after opening them
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,

    // Controls if the editor should automatically format the line after typing
    "editor.formatOnType": false,

    // Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,

    // Controls if suggestions should be accepted 'Enter' - in addition to 'Tab'. Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines or accepting suggestions.
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I just copy pasted your settings into my settings.json file and hit save.  It worked for me, no more intellisense.  Did you edit the file with VS Code and then hit "save" ?  If it didn't work, then maybe try reinstalling vs code and try again.  My bet is that you didn't save.  Also, I opened the file by first going into settings and then clicking on one of the selections that said "edit in settings.json." Another thing that I had to do was after I hit save on the settings.json I also had to go back into settings and manually uncheck all of these options:

[image]

search for "suggestions"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to settings.json. Not a permanent fix, but can act as a temporary one.
The line:

```
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
```

Comment: they already have that.